# WCF, GET and HTTPS

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

I have an WCF REST service with only GET access. I'd like to make it obligatory to use SSL only on several of the service functions.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Intermixing HTTP and HTTPS on the same svc file isn't possible. You need to have an svc file that only talks HTTPS and one that talks HTTP. From my experience trying to get a specific WCF svc to respond in a mixed manner has been impossible.

Comment: somehow I don't use the svc but a .cs file - I used the WCF REST starter kit and it got me without svc. So maybe it could work?

Comment: In theory if you wrote your own implementation of the WebServiceHost you could get around the limitations, but if you are using the default host and factory it will go through the web.config and determine whether or not to let HTTP or HTTPS through to the endpoint (which is really what I was getting at with the svc references)

Answer (score 0):

You need make bindings with using HTTPS protocol + use SSL certificate on IIS